Is there a way to remove a single singing voice from a duet video?
I’m curious to know if there was a way to edit out someone’s voice from a video, please.
My grandad has just passed away, and I have a video of him and his friend singing on karaoke. My grandad enjoyed singing so much, and we always enjoyed listening to him. It would be amazing to be able to get his friend’s voice taken out of the video so that we can use the recording at his funeral.

This question type is common on here, and in fact, this exact question has been asked before and subsequently answered. However, the nature of pro audio means as tech inevitably advances, newer solutions to old questions become apparent, but the original question should then be answered - not the duplicate question. Please see this meta post to learn more. However, as the other question has less relevant answers, time-wise, I will merge it with this one.

I'm afraid this is unlikely to be possible with current technology.
In the past few years, removing a voice from a music track has turned from pipe-dream into reality, using machine learning techniques [often mislabelled Artificial Intelligence].
Removing one voice from another singing in unison or even harmony though, is a whole different level of "AI".
If the voices are on different sides of a stereo file, then you could possibly separate the stereo & process just one side. I'm assuming this is a phone recording with a mono soundtrack, which I think is currently an unreachable goal.

AI can likely do what you need.  About a year ago, a music YouTuber named Rick Beato posted a video on his channel explaining how Paul McCartney and Ringo Starr were able to release a cleaned-up version of an old John Lennon demo recording, separating Lennon's vocal from the piano he was playing.  Beato demonstrated how AI software tools such as the ones at LALAL.AI could be used to do this.  Beato's video can be found here.
There's currently a LALAL.AI tool that appears to do the kind of vocal separation you're looking for.  See https://www.lalal.ai/lead-back-vocals-remover/
I haven't used these tools, so I can't vouch for their usefulness or their ease of use.  In the past year, there are likely other websites / tools that might possibly do the job better.  I'm just passing along some info I learned.  I hope this helps get you the recording you're hoping for.

There are a number of applications that say they can do this. My experience of them is not very deep so I can only put out some ideas.

search on the internet for "vocal remover and isolation"
search for "vocals unmixing"

One program that I have seen (but not really used) is Spectralayers. The Pro version of Davinci Resolve has a function like that as well.

sorry to hear that :/
I don't think you could do this automaticly with AI, but of course you can edit the audio with EQ and loudness automations to at least make your parts less obvious or loud. Afterwards just render a new video with the new soundfile.
If you don't have the tools to do it, I surely could help you out with that :)
My friend makes animated videos and I cut the sounds to his videos so it would be no big deal I gues. Peace
